# Solderable number tag for PCB

Tags: identification

Is there a component with a simple 2-digit number on it (00...99) that can be mounted during standard board assembly process (i.e. pick-and-place machine and reflow)? Something like Molex track-it Traceability Pad but just with a very short human-readable number.

Comment: Can your humans read binary?  If so 7 spots for SMD resistors could work...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfl4F_WQ-uw) is a demo video of a [label feeder](http://label-feeder.com/label-feeder-products/alf12/) that allows label placement using an SMT mounting machine.

[image]

The cost of labels in tape feed that can withstand reflow may be too high for your purposes.

The same process can be used to place polyimide masking dots.

Comment: Do you know if there are pre-printed labels in standard reels compatible with standard pick-and-place process?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used

[image]

That is board number 011. Was done in eagle, I must have the file somewhere, but I probably don't have a functioning eagle any more.

Comment: Was that marked by a selective solder machine or by hand?   Kind of looks like it was done by hand.

Comment: There's nothing to stop it from being done either way I suppose though.

Comment: Those PCBs were all done by hand. Stencil for the solder paste, hand-placed SMDs, simple solder oven (started with a modified toaster oven), through-holes by hand again. I think I did some 100 ~ 150 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your fabricator. It's possible to add labels during assembly (even pre-printed ones).

Comment: Well, not all manufacturers do labels well, especially very small ones for dense boards, so I wanted to make it independent from their assembly capabilities.

Comment: This is the way to go. If a CM can't figure out how to put a frickin label on the board, I don't want them building mine. It's way to standard of an operation to struggle with.

Comment: Labels are one thing.  Labels that will survive nearby re-work and cleaning are another...

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a component?
Since many assembly houses have laser engraving systems. Which is the to-go high volume, easy method to mark boards.

There are also labels, but labels run out and can be taken off.